# symfony Credentials is not working for one particular user?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, credentials

we are developing web portal and we have many credentials to set while user login...but for one particular user,

i.e for admin alone credential is not working.

is there any particular rules for credentials in symfony???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is an super admin, the credentials are ignored. He has ALL the privileges.